# Set height of first row in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I have a basic CSS grid using `display: grid` & I'm unable to set the height of the first row using `grid-template-rows`.

My HTML/CSS looks roughly like this:

```css
.gridWrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto auto;
}

.row1 {
  grid-row-end: 1;
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

.row2 {
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.row3 {
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.col1 {
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column-end: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridWrapper">
  <div class="row1 col1">Col1</div>
  <div class="row1 col2">Col2</div>
  <div class="row2 col1">A</div>
  <div class="row2 col2">B</div>
  <div class="row3 col1">D</div>
  <div class="row3 col2">D</div>
</div>
```

However, it results in this:

[image: 2nd row gets styled, rather than 1st]

This occurs in both latest Chrome & Safari (I'm on Mac), which leads me to believe I've misunderstood something about gridlayout CSS.

How do I set the height of the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - `grid-column-end` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end)) can be a bit misleading. `row1` in your example should have `grid-column-end: 2;` instead of `grid-column-end: 1;`.

To fix this you can just add `1` to every `grid-column-end` and `grid-row-end` property.

Here's snippet with fixed values:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.gridWrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto auto;
}

.row1 {
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

.row2 {
  grid-row-end: 3;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.row3 {
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.col1 {
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridWrapper">
  <div class="row1 col1">Col1</div>
  <div class="row1 col2">Col2</div>
  <div class="row2 col1">A</div>
  <div class="row2 col2">B</div>
  <div class="row3 col1">D</div>
  <div class="row3 col2">D</div>
</div>
```

Also - I don't really see the need for `grid-column-end` here. You can achieve the same result with just `grid-column` and `grid-row` properties (which are less confusing, in my opinion).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.gridWrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto auto;
}

.row1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

.row2 {
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.row3 {
  grid-row: 3;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.col1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.col2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridWrapper">
  <div class="row1 col1">Col1</div>
  <div class="row1 col2">Col2</div>
  <div class="row2 col1">A</div>
  <div class="row2 col2">B</div>
  <div class="row3 col1">D</div>
  <div class="row3 col2">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I somehow missed you can just specify the row/col directly & skip the spanning stuff.  My use case is simple - just a regular grid of 1-unit squares - and `grid-row`/`grid-column` is all I needed

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the `grid-row-end` properties, but you're using the `grid-row-start` lines. That's why things aren't working as you expect.

If you want `.row1` elements to cover the first row, then you need them to span across the row – that means from row line 1 to row line 2.

So instead of this:

- `grid-row-end: 1`

Use any of these this:

- `grid-row-start: 1`
- `grid-row-end: 2`
- `grid-row: 1 / 2`

```css
.gridWrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto auto;
}

.row1 {
  /* grid-row-end: 1; */
  grid-row-end: 2;  /* new */
  background-color: lightslategray;
}

.row2 {
  /* grid-row-end: 2; */
  grid-row-end: 3;  /* new */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.row3 {
  /* grid-row-end: 3; */
  grid-row-end: 4;  /* new */
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.col1 {
  /* grid-column-end: 1; */
  grid-column-end: 2;  /* new */
}

.col2 {
  /* grid-column-end: 2; */
  grid-column-end: 3;  /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="gridWrapper">
  <div class="row1 col1">Col1</div>
  <div class="row1 col2">Col2</div>
  <div class="row2 col1">A</div>
  <div class="row2 col2">B</div>
  <div class="row3 col1">D</div>
  <div class="row3 col2">D</div>
</div>
```